# Is it legal to use #elif with #ifdef?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

A simple question that Google doesn't help me with. Is it legal in C++ to use `#elif` clause in the context of `#ifdef`? It seems to compile and work as expected with all the major compilers in the c++11 mode (MSVC 2015/2017, clang, GCC), but I'm not certain whether it is standard-compliant.

Comment: Yes, it's legal pre-processor speak. An else-if after an if. But, try not to rely too much on pre-processor magic.

Comment: `#elif` can be used with `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, and `#if` equally

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, we can use `#ifdef` with `#elif`. But, If we `#define` macro with value `0` for `#ifdef` case, the `#ifdef` case tests it to true. Otherwise, if we `#define` macro with value `0` for `#elif` case, the `#elif` case test it to **false**.

Comment: @jinbeomhong that is because `#ifdef` tests for a macro's existence, not its value. While `#elif` tests for a macro's value

Comment: @RemyLebeau that was the answer I was looking for. I knew I *could* use #ifdef #elif, but I wondered if the meaning of #elif would change in that context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the grammar allows an `#elif` after preceding, matching `#if`, `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`:

> *if-section*:
>       *if-group* *elif-groups*<sub>opt</sub> *else-group*<sub>opt</sub> *endif-line*
>
> *if-group*:
>       `# if` *constant-expression* *new-line* *group*<sub>opt</sub>
>       `# ifdef` *identifier* *new-line* *group*<sub>opt</sub>
>       `# ifndef` *identifier* *new-line* *group*<sub>opt</sub>

Note that `#ifdef(X)` is just short for `#if defined(X)`, and `#ifndef(X)` for `#if ! defined(X)`.

Answer (score 21):

For me, the most important point on this question is actually [rosshjb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9304999/rosshjb)'s comment under the question:

> @RemyLebeau Yes, we can use #ifdef with #elif. But, If we #define macro with value 0 for #ifdef case, the #ifdef case tests it to true. Otherwise, if we #define macro with value 0 for #elif case, the #elif case test it to false. –
> rosshjb Jan 19 '20 at 19:40

So if you have a block like:

```
#ifdef __linux__
  <some Linux code here>
#elif _WIN32
  <some Windows code here>
#endif
```

Then the second test is significantly different from the first - the first is checking whether `__linux__` is defined at all, where the second is checking that the symbol `_WIN32` evaluates to true. For many cases it will behave the same, but it is not guaranteed to do so.

The full equivalent is actually:

```
#ifdef __linux__
  <some Linux code here>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
  <some Windows code here>
#endif
```

Which is probably not obvious to everyone.

Using [Kerrick SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb)'s answer, you can also write the same `#if` statement as:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
  <some Linux code here>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
  <some Windows code here>
#endif
```

Which makes it more obvious that the `defined` is the same for both the `#if` and the `#elif`

Comment: Good points, thanks for highlighting this. I agree that for multiple branches `#if defined (...)` is much better than the short form `#ifdef`.

Comment: Thank you for the only correct answer that makes sense as well.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's allowed.

The grammar is:

> *if-group elif-groups<sub>opt</sub> else-group<sub>opt</sub> endif-line*

The definition of `if-group` includes not only `#if` but also `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`, so `#ifdef ... #elif ... #endif` is fine.